# Fire destroyListener imemdiately after close Session

Tags: java, vaadin, destroy

I'm working on the session management panel. I want to kill another user`s session by clicking button. I created grid with VaadinSession object and button with VaadinSession.close() functionality but after close() destroy session listener isnt firing immediately and his website isnt reloading. It is fired after some time but when user with closed session  clicks on anything in his website then destroyListener is firing sooner.
Is there any option to fire DestroyListener immediately after closing session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VaadinSession.close()` just [sets a flag](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/59fd55ec5f0e51d10ec806c655e8dae628f00cef/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession.java#L845) stating that the session is going to be closed. The actual cleanup is performed when handling a request from that session. That's why clicking a button triggers the SessionDestroyListener (alternatively, a heartbeat would have the same effect).

With Vaadin 14+, you can force each UI in the closed session to execute a no-operation, so that a server-client rountrip take place.

```
session.getUIs().stream().forEach(ui->ui.getElement().executeJs("return"));
```

At that point:

a) the server will realize that the current session has been closed, then the session will be destroyed (and replaced with a new one)

b) the client will reload each browser tab for the new session.

```
@Push
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

  public MainView() {     
    ApplicationServiceInitListener.sessions.forEach(session->{
      if (session!=VaadinSession.getCurrent()) {
        Button btn = new Button("Close "+session.hashCode());       
        btn.addClickListener(ev->{session.access(()->close(session)); remove(btn);});
        add(btn);
      }});
  }

  private void close(VaadinSession session) {
      session.getUIs().stream().forEach(ui->ui.getElement().executeJs("return"));
      session.close();
  }


}
```

Comment: Many thanks now it is working almost  as i wanted. It is not firing when i'm executing close method but somewhere later in very short time(almost imediatelly).  I`m executing some other method after close() session in this same button actio then this second method is executing before destroyListener and after close method. When this second method will end then listener is executed properly. But i can work with it so many thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

_> It is not firing when i'm executing close method but somewhere later in very short time(almost imediatelly)_
Yes, it's asynchronous: the server communicates with the UI that is being closed, and then the actual destroy takes place.